# How to set height in CSS from JavaScript Variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

So, I am using the Slick slider and wanted to apply some code only when the slider is active.

```
.specialist-description-wrapper {
height: 0rem;
}
.slick-current.slick-active .specialist-description-wrapper {
height: 20rem;
```

}

But the problem is, I don't want to have a fixed height. I want an "Auto" height so if my content gets bigger then it'll fit automatically. If I try to make height from 0rem to Auto then "Transition" doesn't work.

So, I have decided to use JavaScript to calculate the height of the element.

```
    let descriptionWrapper = document.querySelector(".slick-current.slick-active .specialist-description-wrapper")
    let height = descriptionWrapper.offsetHeight
    descriptionWrapper.style.height = height;
```

But it's not working for me. Did I miss something?

Comment: height needs units. But by the time you do this the transition will have taken place. Please show a working snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the height to auto will only take height used by itself and will not take full height.
To make the height responsively adjust according to the parent's height, you can use

```css
height: 100%;
```

This will make the element take all the height of its parent element.

But still, if anything breaks, you can adjust the content of the element. Because the 100% height is important.

---

##### Also, you have not provided enough code regarding your markup. Please always provide the code so that everyone can write better answers for you.